# Estilização do input Date

Tags: html, css

[image: Calendário html]

Bom, queria saber como faço para estilizar um `input` do tipo `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrões estéticos do `input date` vão depender dos navegadores que a suportam. Se quiser uma opção cross-browser e personalizável, terá que usar um plugin, ou algo do tipo. Aqui vai um exemplo com o [`datePicker`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) do Jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Você pode estilizar esse dataPicker com as classes do *Jquery-ui.css*, exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
 background-color: #666;
 border: 1px solid #66AFE9;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
 display: none;
 margin-top: 4px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 240px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.ui-datepicker a{
  color: #f1f2f3  
}
.ui-datepicker a,
.ui-datepicker a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker a:hover,
.ui-datepicker td:hover a {
 color: #2A6496;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
         transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
    margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 text-align: center;
    background: #f1f2f3
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
 cursor: default;
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 height: 20px;
 line-height: 1;
 margin-top: 2px;
 width: 30px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev:before {
 content: "\e079";
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next:before {
 content: "\e080";
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-icon {
 display: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar th,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 4px 0;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td {
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out, color 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out, color 0.1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out, color 0.1s ease-in-out;
         transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out, color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td:hover {
 background-color: #eee;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-current-day {
 background-color: #4289cc;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-current-day a {
 color: #fff
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-datepicker-unselectable:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

[**Guia completo de estilizações**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming)

Comment: vou testar aqui :D valeu!

Comment: @MuriloGambôa, de nada. Qualquer problema, só avisar.